# What does it means if two variable with exactly the same Wald Chi-Square?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, multicollinearity, wald-test

After I run the program, it shows two variables with exactly the same Wald Chi-Square, how can I interpret these statistics?

Can I say that it is Quasi-complete separation that a single level of a categorical input has 100% rate for event for the event of interest? Or can I say it is a problem of collinearity?

Let's say Wald Chi-Square of parameter for Age is 7.8 and Gender is 7.8 as well, as it is test for Significant toward the dependent variable. Can I say these two variable is Quasi-complete separation or a problem of collinearity regarding they have a exactly same value of Wald Chi-Square.

In short, I would like to know same value of Wald Chi-Square of two variables would imply either Quasi-complete separation or collinearity? Or is there any other things should be include to trigger Quasi-complete separation or collinearity.

Comment: Can you share some more of your problem and the output? This is not sufficient information for an answer.

Comment: Sure, edited. Can you help me to clarify my concept?

Comment: There is still not enough information

Comment: In short, I would like to know same value of Wald Chi-Square of two variables would imply either Quasi-complete separation or collinearity? Or is there any other things should be include to trigger Quasi-complete separation or collinearity.

Comment: That two Wald-statistics are exactly equal could just be a coincidence, and probably by itself do not indicate separation. But if separation is your concern, you have not given enough information for us to say somethingh! So please add info on your data, sample size, variables, research design, and maybe plots and some computer output. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask  and  https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/top-k-list-of-reasons-to-close-a-question-immediately

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, and I suspect this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You would be better of asking a question about your real data analysis problem.

But for the question in title:

> In short, I would like to know same value of Wald Chi-Square of two variables would imply either Quasi-complete separation or collinearity?

NO, I can see no reason to believe that. This is most probably an coincidence without any particular meaning.